# Ionic can't find platform

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic3

What is wrong with my config files (OR ionic cordova setup); it can't find any platforms but I do have ios installed already, PLUS ionic tries to add and fails because it exists...  The example below is from emulate, the same errors are generated by `$ionic cordova platform add ios` as well.

```
$ ionic cordova emulate ios
> cordova platform add ios --save
✖ Running command - failed!
[WARN] Platform already added. Saving platforms to config.xml.
> cordova platform save
✔ Running command - done!
[INFO] Running app-scripts build: --platform ios --target cordova

[22:44:34]  build dev started ... 
[22:44:34]  clean started ... 
[22:44:34]  clean finished in 11 ms 
[22:44:34]  copy started ... 
[22:44:34]  transpile started ... 
[22:44:38]  transpile finished in 4.45 s 
[22:44:38]  preprocess started ... 
[22:44:38]  deeplinks started ... 
[22:44:39]  deeplinks finished in 264 ms 
[22:44:39]  preprocess finished in 265 ms 
[22:44:39]  webpack started ... 
[22:44:39]  copy finished in 4.89 s 
[22:44:50]  webpack finished in 11.63 s 
[22:44:50]  sass started ... 
[22:44:51]  sass finished in 1.04 s 
[22:44:51]  postprocess started ... 
[22:44:51]  removed unused font files 
[22:44:51]  postprocess finished in 10 ms 
[22:44:51]  lint started ... 
[22:44:51]  build dev finished in 17.47 s 
> ionic cordova prepare
[WARN] No Cordova platforms listed in config.xml. Nothing to prepare.

   You can save your installed platforms to config.xml with the ionic cordova platform save command.
[22:44:53]  lint finished in 2.11 s
```

And this is my config.xml file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.nkt.pms" version="2.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>Sys</name>
<description>System</description>
<author email="support@XXXX.net" href="http://XXXX">The XXXX Team</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://XXXX:8100" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
<preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
    <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
    <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
    <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
    <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
    <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
    <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
    <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
    <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
    <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
    <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
    <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
    <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
    <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
    <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
    <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
    <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
    <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
    <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
    <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
    <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
    <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
    <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
    <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
    <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
    <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
</platform>
<feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar" />
</feature>
<icon src="resources/newicon.png" />
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" spec="~2.4.1">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value=" " />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="^1.1.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-customurlscheme" spec="^4.3.0">
    <variable name="URL_SCHEME" value="com.nkt.pms" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_SCHEME" value="com.nkt.pms" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_HOST" value="pmsys.eu.auth0.com" />
    <variable name="ANDROID_PATHPREFIX" value="/cordova/com.nkt.pms/callback" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" spec="~4.3.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" spec="~1.6.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-filepath" spec="~1.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-safariviewcontroller" spec="^1.4.7" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.3" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-sqlite-storage" spec="^2.0.4" />
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

```
$ ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/larsbrenna/Desktop/dev/app/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Cordova Platforms  : ios
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

Node  : v6.9.1
npm   : 5.4.2 
OS    : macOS Sierra
Xcode : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Any and all tips and hints appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ionic can't find the platform because the `<engine>` tag is missing in `config.xml`. Try cleaning up your setup a bit:

- Run `cordova platform rm ios` (you may get an error that the platform is not added)
- Remove the `platforms` folder if it still exists
- Maybe also remove the `plugins` folder if you want them reinstalled
- Remove all references related to the ios platform in `package.json`
- Delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`

Then make sure cordova and ionic CLIs are up to date:

```
(sudo) npm install -g cordova@latest ionic@latest
```

Then restore everything step by step:

- `npm install`
- `cordova platform add ios@4.5.1`

I personally like to run the `cordova` commands just through the cordova CLI not via the ionic CLI (when running `ionic cordova ...` the ionic CLI just forwards cordova related commands to the cordova CLI, which can lead to errors). Just for building and running the app I use the combined commands because its more convenient.

I also noticed that you are using an old version of `@ionic/app-scripts` with the newest `ionic-angular` version. You should upgrade this too.

Comment: Many thanks! The app now runs via XCode, but not directly from Ionic CLI:
`    > cordova emulate ios
Error: Command failed: xcrun simctl list --json
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Developer/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSimulator.framework/Versions/A/CoreSimulator
  Referenced from: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/simctl
  Reason: image not found

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova emulate ios (exit code 1).`

Comment: You probably need to update XCode and/or XCode commandline tools to the latest version. Also make sure you restart your mac once in a while, so nothing gets locked up with all the updating :)

Comment: I'm running XCode 9.0 (latest). Oh, and ionic serve fails too.. Will try again after a reboot! :)